# CSS transparent mask/knockout

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to find a good way in CSS to create a mask where the mask is knocked out and I can pass another image or div behind it.

an example of what I was trying to work with is here
http://jsfiddle.net/LxBM5/
the problem in that example is that I need to be able to use gradient color rather than a solid block I have in the jsfiddle example

This is what I was trying to get working when you hold the mouse down over the image you will see a solid black bar when you drap over the little face, but I need a way to show another image or gradient that still goes behind the mask.

```
<div class="mask">
    <div class="image">
    </div>
</div>
```

```css
.mask {
    position: relative;
    width: 500px;
    height: 300px;
    background: url(http://i.imgur.com/dyFDLPp.png) top left no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}

.image {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
    height: 400px;
    background: url(http://i.imgur.com/zbK3Ps2.png) top left no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    display: none;
}
```

```
var mousedown = false;
$('.mask').on('mousedown mouseup', function () {
    mousedown = !mousedown
    if (mousedown) {
        $('.image').css({
            display: 'block'
        });
    } else {
        $('.image').css({
            display: 'none'
        });
    }
});
$('.mask').on('mousemove', function (e) {
    if (mousedown) {
        $('.image').css({
            top: e.clientY - 50,
            left: e.clientX - 50
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Are you trying to do this: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/VmsRt/

Comment: No sorry, so there are basically 3 items at play here, the original image remains exactly in tact, it will be say a jpg with no alpha channel.   The second image is a mask that creates a knockout from the first image.  a third item would be a gradient image that passes between the original image and the mask so it appears when anomated to be shiny, ONLY where the parts that are knocked out are.  Think of a business card that has shiny spots on the front but not the entire card, and when you slowly tile the card in the light you see the shiny parts only where they were printed as such.

Comment: Actually I don't see any difference apart from your example except that mine isn't a rectangle (which can be made into a rectangle by setting the width)... But anyway, good luck with your project.

Comment: Oh I see what your are trying to do. Have you tried use the `mask` in CSS3?

Answer (score 3):

Update your image?

### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LxBM5/3/

```
.mask {
    position: absolute;
    width: 50px;
    height: 400px;
    background: url(http://tinyurl.com/k8vzdo2) top left no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Touche :-) I tend to agree.